# gTouches error without geometry error?

Tags: r, geos

I have a map showing administrative boundaries (available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9988cmads19u7ps/AAAVQGUfR1SG94crfV-vaHrca?dl=0)).  I've loaded it into R and have attempted to run `gTouches` (from rgeos) to determine which areas are adjacent to which, but receive an error:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)

> Districts <- readOGR(... )
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile
with 9235 features and 16 fields
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions

> adj <- gTouches(Districts)
Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_touches") : 
  TopologyException: side location conflict at 34.353274826787519 -15.739538287828307
```

After Googling that error I found a lot of advice about "bad geometries."  Following that I took the file into QGIS (following advice here from Faunalia's "Bad, bad polygon" document) and ArcMap (using Python code [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000)) and run the geometry checking/repair tools. Neither program found an error.

I've zoomed my map into the offending coordinates but don't see anything that appears wrong--it's a location where two lines come together near another vertex.

How do I repair the geometry, ignore that particular region, or some other R function that might work better than `gTouches`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
adj <- gTouches(Districts, byid = TRUE)
```

This produced a matrix indicating which regions share a border with other regions.